# RDP over SSH standard port

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2016

Due to firewall reasons, I have changed the standard RDP port by the port 22 by following this:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/change-listening-port

After reboot, I try to connect with remote desktop using IP:22 but I have no answer. Of course, I have no answer anymore from port 3389.

Is it possible to do a RDP connection via port 22? If so, how can I debug deeply?

I have opened my firewall to allow incoming connections through port 22.

Comment: What happens when you just ssh using PuTTY or similar to your network?  Do you get a login prompt from your router?  Some routers have a built-in `sshd` that may need to be turned off first.

Comment: It would be easier to change your firewall to allow 3389, but look at this Microsoft article to see if it helps you change the port number:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/change-listening-port

Comment: @LawrenceC Another Linux machines in the same subnetwork are reachable through ssh, that’s why I thought that using port 22 for RDP should work

Comment: @John Yes, this is exactly the article I followed to change the port. Unfortunately I have no rights to manage the firewall

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio basically the router may be listening on port 22 and not letting anything through.

Comment: @LawrenceC Dont think so because if I change the windows VM for a Linux one, the SSH connection is properly established